# "Hopf bundles" are indeed bundles.

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology

Can someone provide a reference to a verification that "Hopf bundles" are indeed bundles? Thanks. I could not find a mention of this in Hatcher...

Comment: The wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_bundle gives conditions in terms of the differentiable structure (surjective submersion with compact connected fibers) that imply a map is a fiber bundle. This should be satisfied for the Hopf maps. I'm sure there are other ways...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find an explicit description of the Hopf bundles at the beginning of the book [Geometry, Topology and Gauge Fields](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4419-7895-0) by G. L. Naber (start from page 25).